# How do parse a text file for the line after a phrase in r?

Tags: r, parsing

I have a large text file with 40,000+ sections of output.  Each output section is ~150 lines. I want one number from each section to put in a vector.  The section I want to parse is shown as below.

```
Min ChiSq_Th:     ith_cs  ith_rk
                  -1       1
      chisq_th  chisq_th_min  chisq_th_max      ftmp_imv      fstp_imv
  0.149282D+05  0.200268D+05  0.200268D+05  0.100000D+01  0.100000D+00
```

I need the number below `chisq_th` in each sweep. I tried taking every 152nd line but not every sweep is exactly the same. I know R is not the ideal platform for this problem but it is the language I know best.

Comment: you could try `z<-readLines("mytxt"); z[which(grepl("chisq_th", z))+1]`

Comment: Search for `chisq_th` then add 1 like jeremy suggested. If you have a data frame `my_data[grep("chisq_th", my_data[,"column"]) + 1, ]` where "column" is the column with chisq.

Comment: @jeremycg `which(grepl(..` is the same as `grep(..`